# Python For Loop of Data Frame taking Header row while Building SQL String

Tags: python, sql

I'm trying to attach some databases to a SQL server using a loop in Python. When executing the dynamic SQL string I'm getting the error below. The loop seems to be taking the header and feeding this as a variable into the dynamic SQL, as 'DATABASE' is a column header in the data frame. I want to take the first row of data from the data frame not the header. New to Python if it wasn't obvious.

> ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]A file activation error occurred. The physical file name 'Database' may be incorrect. Diagnose and correct additional errors, and retry the operation. (5105) (SQLExecDirectW)")

```
import os
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

path = []
databases = []

path = 'Z:\Test\\'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'Z:\Test'):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.mdf'):
            databases.append([os.path.splitext(file)[0], path + file])

df = pd.DataFrame(databases, columns = ['Database','DatabasePath'])

conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=Test;'
                      'Database=Master;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
                      'autocommit=True;')

cursor = conn.cursor()

for x in df:
    SQL = """DECLARE @SQL as nvarchar(max) set @SQL = N'CREATE DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME(?) + N' ON (FILENAME = N''' + REPLACE(?,'''','''''') + N''') FOR ATTACH;';
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;"""
    cursor.execute(SQL, (x,x))
```

Comment: Any advice on this please. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below did the trick. I added `i` for the index of the `for` loop and also applied `iterrows()` to get the rows and named the columns required in the `cursor.execute()`

```
for i, x in df.iterrows():
    SQL = """DECLARE @SQL as nvarchar(max) set @SQL = N'CREATE DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME(?) + N' ON (FILENAME = N''' + REPLACE(?,'''','''''') + N''') FOR ATTACH;';
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;"""
    cursor.execute(SQL, (x['Database'],x['DatabasePath']))
```